# pygame get_pressed stays true

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game in which you move a character with the arrow keys on the keyboard. Since my laptop sometimes think that I pressed a key twice i wanted to make sure that the program waited until I released the pressed key. I use the `key.get_pressed()` method. The problem is that when I press a key, the action is executed, but the loop waiting for the keys to be released keeps running because the `get_pressed()` event thinks that i still pressed the button. Here is the code:

```
while ChangeRun == False: # main game loop
    for Event in pygame.event.get():
        if Event == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    BUTTON = -1
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
        BUTTON = 0
    elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
        BUTTON = 1
    elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_RIGHT]:
        BUTTON = 2
    elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT]:
        BUTTON = 3
    elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_p]:
        BUTTON = 4
    elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_RETURN]:
        BUTTON = 5


    if BUTTON == 4 or BUTTON == 5:
        Execute()
    elif BUTTON != -1:
        SetDirection()

    DisplaySurface() # Displays all data on screen
    # it works until these rows:
    while pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP] or pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN] or pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT] or pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_RIGHT] or pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_p] or pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_RETURN]:
        pass # Keeps running because the get_pressed() method thinks one of the buttons is still pressed...
```

I checked what was wrong by printing all `get_pressed()` values.
It showed that the button I pressed keeps returning true, even when i released it.

I hope it's clear and that someone could help.

Comment: So you want your character to move only once every time you press and release a key?

Comment: Why don't you get the key pressed in the `for Event in pygame.event.get` a lot easier to me, but i agree with Dominic, you set the Button to `-1` each time through, so should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you read my comment, but personally the following is how I would do it, this is because you check for an event then check what that event was it's just a bit more full proof.

This is obviously inside your while loop.

```
BUTTON = -1

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    elif event.type in [KEYDOWN, KEYUP]:
        if event.key == K_UP:
            BUTTON = 0
        elif event.key == K_DOWN:
            BUTTON = 1
        #and so on
```

and then at the end use...

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type in [KEYDOWN, KEYUP]:
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_SPACE:
                pass
            else:
                break
```

This is because pygame.event.get() remove all events from the queue and so if you call it again it should have nothing unless, like Dominic said, your keyboard is broken.

Comment: I got an error trying this: `NameError: name 'KEY_PRESSED' is not defined`

Comment: I replaced the `KEY_PRESSED` event for `KEYDOWN` in the first part and in the second part `if event.type in [KEYDOWN, KEYUP]`. Now it seems to work.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry i should've been paying more attention when answering, my avar had now been edited